# Dynamic Drawable: How to draw a line defined by two points, which can be redrawn if one of the points changes?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I want to draw an updatable line between point (0/0) and point (1/1), which can be used as a drawable (view background). Whenever one of the point changes, the line shall be redrawn.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to write my own class inherited from the drawable class, but I couldn't find out how to use this custom class like a regular drawable in the android layout files.